# Power bi - User retention rate calculation

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop

I'm fairly new to Power bi and have tried and searched for this almost all the forums but couldn't find anything similar to mine.

So.. I have a table like the following (Something similar)

[image]

I would like to calculate the retention rate of the users (who actually came back).

What I have done so far:

> RetentionRate = (ReturningUsers / PreviousDayDistinctUsers)*100%
>
> ReturningUsers = DistinctUsers - NewUsers
>
> PreviousDayDistinctUsers = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(table[User], PREVIOUSDAY(table[Date])
>
> NewUsers = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(table[User] ), table[MonthlyNewUsers] = BLANK () )

The above looks to be working, but the only drawback was with the `PreviousDayDistinctUsers` as it is only considering the previous day (Not all the days from the starting to that day).

So how do I write a **measure to calculate the DistinctUsers for all the days until today**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PreviousDayDistinctUsers =
   VAR Current_Day = LASTDATE ( table[Date] )
   RETURN 
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( table[User] ), table[Date] < Current_Day )
```

How it works: 
First, save last date in a filter context into a variable (instead of LASTDATE, you can also use MAX function). 
Second, filter table User by all dates that are less than the saved date, and count distinct users in the filtered table.